# Grouping data points into a cluster

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, simulation, astronomy

I am trying to follow a cluster of data points and investigate the rms radius of the cluster over time. However, I am unsure how to go about doing this if I am only looking trying to group some of my data into 1 cluster.

I am trying to group particles in an n-body simulation which can be shown below, ignoring the particles lost at the start.

I have come across varying cluster algorithms such as Kmeans and DBSCAN but am unsure how to use these if I am only looking to get one cluster for only a percentage of my data, and then use these to find the rms radius of my cluster.

[image: gif of simulation]

Answer (score 0):

You said you want to investigate A cluster of data points since you put all data points to one cluster. So, you can define a radius for this group (you don't need to have more than one cluster to define the radius of a group).

One way is to define a centroid and compute its distance from its futhest neighbor data point in the group. Another way is to use min-max concept, the minimum distance between two farthest point (The minimum radius to cover all data points having assumed that the centroid is a member of the group)

Comment: How do I begin doing this though? As the cluster moves over time, I would need to find the centroid of the cluster somehow before I can begin to calculate its radius?

Comment: @ Oliver Moore: Please let me first confirm my understanding. You have several data points ALL in one group at initial time t0. Then at time t1, your group changes but again you have ONLY one group with some data points. And so on. Right? If that's the case and you KNOW you have only one group, why are you using clustering techniques?? You already know that all data points belong to one cluster. So, now you need to calculate centroid given the fact that you have the data points and all of them are in one cluster.

Comment: Google finding centroid or radius of a cluster if you still have difficulty understanding my answer since you are probably not familiar with a stage of clustering process that is regard to finding centroid. You can use that concept for your work as I explained in my answer. I think it is better if you read a short article about clustering process and finding centroids. (Also search about hierarchcial clustering with min max linkage and you can apply that comcept to your work)

Comment: So as seen in the gif all the particles start with random positions within a sphere and then evolve under gravity. As the particles collapse, they form the cluster seen in the gif which slowly moves in the negative z-direction. But yes I only have one group or cluster which is the 'blob' of particles seen moving on the gif, however, the other particles 'lost' at the start of the simulation are still there they are just off the graph. My question is more if I know I have a cluster how do I find the centroid of it at a given time frame, ignoring the other particles. Thanks

Comment: I know how to find the centre of mass of the system, it's just the issue of just finding the centre of mass of the cluster, not the whole system.

Comment: So, you know how to calculate the center of mass of system if I tell you this system has N points with this and that coordinates. Right? So, your system is now just ONE cluster (i.e ONE group) of data points. Why don't you treat it as a new system and calculate the centroid given the coordinates and information you have about its members? (I assume you know what points are members of yoir group at each time. Right?) I still don't get your problem

Comment: In my code, I currently have no way of deciding whether a particle is in the group or not. I need to find some way to select the data points that are part of the cluster but am unsure of how to do this as the cluster moves over time.

Comment: Do you know the members of your group at each time? Do you know how to ignore particles that are being lost in the beginning? If so, you have data points of your cluster. You have your new system. So do whatever you do as you have only one system (your group of points at time (t))

Comment: I see. I understand NOW. You should revise your question. What you are looking for is detecting outliers or anomaly. Google about it and if you still cannot find answer, then revise your question to get better chance of getting related answer here. Unfortunately I don't have enough info on outliers/anomaly. Good luck.

Comment: Just one last thought. You can always find the closest neighbor of each point. So, for N data points, you can find N corresponding neighbors that are closest to them. Among those, choose the one with largest distance. It means you have a point whose distance from its closest point is the largest. That's outlier. You can remove one by one until the rate of change of your radius becomes negligible (less than a threshold). You can say then you successfully renoved the outliers and all is left are the members.